# SwiftUI specify type when it cannot be inferred

Tags: ios, swiftui

```
GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
        .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(count) / 2), height: geometry.size.height)
        .offset(x: 2 * (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(count) / 2) * CGFloat(index) - geometry.size.width / 2 + (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(count) / 2) / 2)
    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
}
```

What I want is to declare a variable like this (or put it inside forEach, that doesn't really matter)

```
GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
    let size = (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(count) / 2)
    return ForEach(0..<5) { index in
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
        .frame(width: size, height: geometry.size.height)
        .offset(x: 2 * size * CGFloat(index) - geometry.size.width / 2 + size / 2)
    }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
}
```

Both options give compile errors about failing to infer content types. I used to resolve this by force casting to `AnyView` and specifying `AnyView` as a Group content type. But since SwiftUI 5.2 animation stopped working for `AnyView` for some reason. So firstly, what type should I specify if compiler couldn't infer it? And secondly, why did AnyView animations stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decomposition is first thing which comes into mind in such situations... Here is possible solution:

```
    // somewhere in body
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            self.row(for: index, size: geometry.size.width / CGFloat(count) / 2, geometry: geometry)
        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
    ...

// somewhere below in struct
private func row(for index: Int, size: CGFloat, geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
        .frame(width: size, height: geometry.size.height)
        .offset(x: 2 * size * CGFloat(index) - geometry.size.width / 2 + size / 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first code snippet works for me, I only changed "self.count". Here is my test code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var count = 5

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2), height: geometry.size.height)
                .offset(x: 2 * (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2) * CGFloat(index) - geometry.size.width / 2 + (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2) / 2)
        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```

If your question is specifically about creating a var from this, then no problem:

```
var body: some View {
    myVar
}

var myVar: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ForEach(0..<5) { index in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                .frame(width: (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2), height: geometry.size.height)
                .offset(x: 2 * (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2) * CGFloat(index) - geometry.size.width / 2 + (geometry.size.width / CGFloat(self.count) / 2) / 2)
        }.frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
}
```